# Update bg colour of text input in html form via javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, html-input

I have a form that I want to validate before the user is able to submit it. To do this I have written a basic js file that checks a value is not left blank. In the event that this is the case I want the background colour of the text field to update to be red. I have looked around online and am struggling to get this working. Here is what I have so far:

**HTML Form:**

```
<script language="javascript" src="validateForm.js"></script>
<form name="contact form">
    <input  type="text" name="name"></td>
    <input type="button" value="Send" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
</form>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function validateForm()
{
var result = true;
var form = document.forms["contact form"];

// Name
var name = form["name"].value;
if ( name == null || name == "" )
{
    form["name"].style.backgroundColor = red;
    result = false;
}

return result;
}
```

Please could someone help me get this working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use red as string ( you missed the quote)  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vQ3rX/)

```
form["name"].style.backgroundColor = "red"; // not red
```